# How to run overdue at jobs

Tags: shell, at

Sometimes I have `at` jobs overdue after system-suspend that don't run after waking up. How can I tell `atd` to run them? I tried `atd -s` or `atrun` but I guess that isn't meant for this as it doesn't run the overdue jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing an empty job `at NOW` seems to do it. Run `crontab -e` and add the line

`* * * * * echo | at NOW`

to check every minute.